# All combinations of ranges given an 'anchor' and 'reach'

Tags: python

Let's say I have an 'anchor' number of 8, and a 'reach' number of 2. What's the best way to produce a python list of lists as below? The 'reach' number is the maximum number of digits away from your 'anchor' number you wish to generate combinations for.

`[[8], [8,9], [8,9,10], [7,8], [6,7,8], [7,8,9], [6,7,8,9], [7,8,9,10], [6,7,8,9,10]]`

Note that I don't want `[6, 8]` or `[8, 10]` or `[6,8,9]` etc. because there are numbers missing in between.

Order doesn't matter for the lists or the lists-of-lists.

Thanks!

Comment: "Note that I don't want [6, 8] or [8, 10] or [6,8,9] etc. because there are numbers missing in between." - your logic is not clear, how do you decide what should go in and what not?

Comment: Can you explain *'anchor' number of 8, and a 'reach' number of 2* on code? or can you show that whats the role of **2** within your expected output?

Comment: first write some code and play on it.

Comment: "Any continuous sequence of numbers containing the anchor number, for which every element is at most reach numbers away."?

Comment: I understand the goal. Get all combinations of values without gaps between the numbers, from 6-10, (8 - 2/+2). It's probably easier to think of it as lower bound 6 and upperbound 10 (+4), rather than middle bound 8 (-2 and +2). Ah, except for the fact you want `[8]`. Very interesting problem.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yes, but the combination must contain the 'anchor' number.

Comment: Somebody tells me whats the role of 2 :((( if 8 +2 so whats the 7?

Comment: @Krasra 2 is the number of digits away from the anchor number +/-. I'll try to clarify in question.

Comment: @EmilBrundage Did you mean 2 is the **max** number away from anchor?

Comment: @Kasra correct. Sorry it wasn't more clear in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> def list_maker(anchor, reach):
...     return [list(range(anchor-r, anchor+x+1)) for r in range(reach+1) for x in range(reach+1)]
...
>>> list_maker(8, 2)
[[8], [8, 9], [8, 9, 10], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Very nice. No one replied for 15 minutes. Well done for being the first with even an efficient solution :)

Comment: @PascalvKooten I suspect that nobody replied because the problem was not too difficult and answerers were hoping to see the OP's own attempt first.

Comment: @Sam That's not how it works at SO. People complain while other people answer the question and get upvotes. No one replied though for 15 minutes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Now I have homework - figuring out how it works.